# I am not able to open a .jar file in Ubuntu 18.04.4

Tags: java

I am  new to Linux and want some help regarding Java apps.
I have some .jar files which I have imported from another mobile device.
I have Installed `default-jre` package from `apt`.
When I launch `java -jar app.jar`, I receive, `no main manifest attribute` error message.
Please help.

PS: Neither do I own the packages nor know anything about Java programming.

Comment: @turbulence, in the jar file there is a directory META-INF/MANIFEST.MF. I don't know how to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

The jar file must have MANIFEST file in it which tells the compiler which class has the main method. Since this file/information is missing in the jar file, you need to know the fully qualified name of this class, e.g.

```
java -cp app.jar com.somepackage.SomeClass
```

We can find this special class even if we do not have the source files.
e.g. Download a helloworld file without the `main manifest attribute` from [java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/helloworld-/helloworld-2.2.jar.zip).

```
mkdir hello && mv helloworld-2.2.jar.zip hello
unzip helloworld-2.2.jar.zip
unzip helloworld-2-2.jar
grep -nr main .
```

This' output

```
Binary file ./org/glassfish/jersey/examples/helloworld/App.class matches
```

Here we know which file contains the main method. To get the "Fully Qualified Class Name", we replace '/'s with '.'s. Now we have two options

1. We pass the class name to java command.

   java -cp helloworld-2.2.jar org.glassfish.jersey.examples.helloworld.App
2. Install default-jdk, and update the jar manifest file with this class name

```
jar -uvfe helloworld-2.2.jar org.glassfish.jersey.examples.helloworld.App
java -jar helloworld-2.2.jar
```